# Docker overlay2 files missing empty after restart (Ubuntu 14.04)

Tags: docker, ubuntu-14.04

I am running docker version `17.09.0-ce` on `Ubuntu 14.04`. Recently the server got shutdown due to power outrage and after restarting the container files are missing.

I get a error as,

> “Error response from daemon: stat /var/lib/docker/overlay2/45a12e7da38cfd47a746977ea14664c9f4d94c2758726b9390df4d99732378bb: no such file or directory”.

I can see the volumes are indeed present under `/var/lib/docker/volumes/` and the containers are present under `/var/lib/docker/containers/`.
Is there any way to recover this?

```sh
Containers: 3
 Running: 0
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 3
Images: 4
Server Version: 17.09.0-ce
Storage Driver: overlay2
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
 Supports d_type: true
 Native Overlay Diff: false
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: bridge host macvlan null overlay
 Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file logentries splunk syslog
Swarm: inactive
Runtimes: runc
Default Runtime: runc
Init Binary: docker-init
containerd version: 06b9cb35161009dcb7123345749fef02f7cea8e0
runc version: 3f2f8b84a77f73d38244dd690525642a72156c64
init version: 949e6fa
Security Options:
 apparmor
Kernel Version: 4.4.0-31-generic
Operating System: Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 2
Total Memory: 7.638GiB
Name: phoenix-OptiPlex-780
ID: U5HF:J5E3:VMLY:5TGC:VZRF:GF3V:W2H4:VSZZ:5TDY:B3JX:6UJH:ORIR
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): false
No Proxy: 161.85.19.106
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Experimental: false
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
Live Restore Enabled: false

WARNING: No swap limit support
```

Comment: you need to re-create the container

Comment: By recreating how do i ensure the same volumes will be mounted?